# Rails routing: id doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, hyperlink

I have the following routing rule:

match ':controller/:action/:id'

However when I use

```
<%= link_to "Link", :action => "some_action", :id => 10 %>
```

Instead of redirecting to "some_action/10" it redirects to "some_action?id=10"

How can I fix that?

P.S. I know I should be using the path methods, but is there a way to avoid them?

Comment: That should theoretically work. Are you sure there aren't any other routes getting in the way? (Also, I'd generally recommend against leaving the catch-all rule in place. The routes file exists so that you can specify.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Matchu said, it should work. Try making your catch-all route the first one in routes.rb. If it works then, you'll know there's another route being evaluated first.

If this doesn't work, post your complete routes.rb file.

Comment: Thank you guys! I just had to move it up. It works great now.